# ARM template adminPassword is null for Uri file deployment but not for local files

Tags: azure, powershell, deployment

In PowerShell I deploy a simple ARM template with a SQL Server 2022 VM.
I pass the adminPassword parameter as a securestring to the cmdlet New-AzResourceGroupDeployment in my script and it works fine, when the parameter file and template file are locally on my machine in Windows.

```
# This one works fine:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateParameterFile parameters.json -TemplateFile template.json -adminPassword $adminPassword
```

But the parameterpassing of adminPassword does not work, when I point directly to the files in GitHub. I get an error which says the adminPassword parameter is null

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -adminPassword $adminPassword -TemplateParameterUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/camillagaardsted/dp300/main/Lab1VM/parameters.json -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/camillagaardsted/dp300/main/Lab1VM/template.json
```

My complete script can be found here:
https://github.com/camillagaardsted/dp300/blob/main/Lab1VM/deployvm.ps1
I know it's not best practice to save a password in a script, but it's for a short demo and I don't want to use Azure key vault in this case.

Why does it fail with with the github files and not with the local ones?

Comment: I have tried to deploy the above shared arm template in my subscription with `adminpassword` value as `null` in parameters.json file and able to deploy the vm successfully as shown in this image https://i.imgur.com/zq9jKBm.png

Comment: It's when I use the TemplateParameterUri parameterset it fails. The local download of the template files works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the similar approach in my environment by referring to this MSDoc
[Create a virtual machine and deploy it using ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template#create-a-virtual-machine). Provided parameters by `parameters.json` file containing `adminusername` & `adminpassword(secure string)`.  The deployment was successful, with no admin password null errors by `templateuri`.

***Note***: Probably, you should upgrade Azure PowerShell version and test it if it is working with `templateuri`.

***Sample code snippet:***

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/xxxxxdeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "secureString",
      "minLength": <userdefined>
    }
  }
}
```

`vm.json`:

[image]

`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`:

```
 New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroup> -TemplateUri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/xxxazuredeploy.json" -adminUsername <xxxadminUsername> -adminPassword <securedadminPassword> -dnsLabelPrefix <dnsLabelPrefix>
```

[image]

***Deployed in Portal:***

[image]

Comment: This one worked succesfully yesterday, so it works fine with just a templateUri:

    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
 -TemplateUri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.sql/sql-logical-server/azuredeploy.json" `
 -administratorLogin $adminUser -administratorLoginPassword $adminPassword


The problem arises when I have a template parameter file together with a templateUri. The files are generated via the Create VM wizard in the portal.